# Write an algorithm to count the number of sub-dictionaries in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm fairly new to Python and I'm struggling with nested dictionaries. Consider this dictionary of dictionaries:

```
d = {
  'a1': {
    'a2': [
      [1, 2, 3],
      {
        'a3': ({
          'a4': 'cv'
        }, (1, 2, 3, {
          'a5': 'c'
        }))
      }
    ]
  },
  'b1': {
    'b2': [1, 2, 3]
  },
  3: '3',
  (1, 2, 3): 'immutable'
}
```

How to count the sub-dict from the dictionary `d`.

And my algorithm for this is incorrect:

```
def count_dict(d):
    # print(d.items())
    return sum(1 + count_dict(v) if isinstance(v, dict) else 1 for _, v in d.items())

$> print(count_dict(d))
$> 6
```

and the expect result is 9.

Comment: Am I blind or is there no "b" in that dict?

Comment: There are only 6 dicts in `d` (`d` included) if I count them right

Comment: yeah, I think maybe he means how many key-value pairs, it is 9 for key-value pairs. @pLOPeGG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all dict by recursion. Before that, here are something I must clarify:

1. find in dictionary `d` not dictionary `b`, right?
2. if you want to find all dictionary, it has 6 `dict` in examples. if you want to find all `key-value pairs`, it has 9 `key-value pairs`.

So I have right two versions, one count for `dict`, and one count for `key-value` (just one-line difference):

```
def count_dict(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        # count 1 if it is a dict
        count = 1
        # iterate values for dict
        iterable = d.values()
    else:
        count = 0
        iterable = d

    for v in iterable:
        if isinstance(v, dict) or isinstance(v, list) or isinstance(v, tuple) or isinstance(v, set):
            # count recursively
            count += count_dict(v)
    return count


def count_dict_pairs(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        # count key-value pairs if it is a dict
        count = len(d)
        iterable = d.values()
    else:
        count = 0
        iterable = d

    for v in iterable:
        if isinstance(v, dict) or isinstance(v, list) or isinstance(v, tuple) or isinstance(v, set):
            count += count_dict(v)
    return count

def test():
    d = {
        'a1': {
            'a2': [
                [1, 2, 3],
                {
                    'a3': ({
                               'a4': 'cv'
                           }, (1, 2, 3, {
                        'a5': 'c'
                    }))
                }
            ]
        },
        'b1': {
            'b2': [1, 2, 3]
        },
        3: '3',
        (1, 2, 3): 'immutable'
    }

    print(count_dict(d))   # output 6
    print(count_dict_pairs(d))   # output 9
```

Hope it help you.

Comment: Thank you very much, I means key-value pairs, and I confused the concept of the python dictionary.